# get the number of character vector elements in a corpus

Tags: r, word-count, sentiment-analysis, word-frequency, lexicon

my goal is to use R for lexicon based sentiment analysis!

i have two character vectors. one with positive words and one with negative words.
e.g.

```
pos <- c("good", "accomplished", "won", "happy")
neg <- c("bad", "loss", "damaged", "sued", "disaster")
```

i now have a corpus of thousands of news articles and i want to know for each article, how
many elements of my vectors pos and neg are in the article.

e.g. (not sure about how the corpus function works here but you get the idea: there are two articles in my corpus)

```
mycorpus <- Corpus("The CEO is happy that they finally won the case.", "The disaster caused a huge loss.")
```

i want to get something like this:

```
article 1: 2 element of pos and 0 element of neg
article 2: 0 elements of pos, 2 elements of neg
```

another good thing would be, if i can get the following for each article:

(number of pos words - number of neg words)/(number of total words in article)

thank you very much!!

EDIT:

@ Victorp: this doesn't seem to work

the matrix i get looks good:

```
mytdm[1:6,1:10]
               Docs
Terms          1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
aaron          0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0  0
abandon        1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0
abandoned      0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0  0
abbey          0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0
abbott         0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0
abbotts        0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0  0
```

but when i do your command i get zero for every document!

```
colSums(mytdm[rownames(mytdm) %in% pos, ])
   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15 
   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 
  16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29   30 
   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

why is that??

Comment: Do `sum(rownames(mytdm) %in% pos)` for check if you have positive words in your matrix, it's an exact matching so the words have to be written the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you can use the TermDocumentMatrix for doing that :

```
mycorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(c("The CEO is happy that they finally won the case.", "The disaster caused a huge loss.")))
mytdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(mycorpus, control=list(removePunctuation=TRUE))
mytdm <- as.matrix(mytdm)

# Positive words
colSums(mytdm[rownames(mytdm) %in% pos, ])
1 2 
2 0 

# Negative words
colSums(mytdm[rownames(mytdm) %in% neg, ])
1 2 
0 2 

# Total number of words per documents
colSums(mytdm)
1 2 
9 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach:

```
## pos <- c("good", "accomplished", "won", "happy")
## neg <- c("bad", "loss", "damaged", "sued", "disaster")
## 
## mycorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(
##     list("The CEO is happy that they finally won the case.", 
##     "The disaster caused a huge loss.")))

library(qdap)
with(tm_corpus2df(mycorpus), termco(text, docs, list(pos=pos, neg=neg)))

##   docs word.count       pos       neg
## 1    1         10 2(20.00%)         0
## 2    2          6         0 2(33.33%)
```

Comment: hey tyler, thanks for your answer! what does tm_corpus2df(mycorpus) mean? do you transform the corpus into a data frame with this function? and "text" and "docs" are my column names i guess?

Comment: Yes `tm_corpus2df(mycorpus)` converts to a data.frame as is the data format used in qdap.  And yes "text" and "docs" are the defualt names given by `tm_corpus2df`. You could change them if you desire.

Comment: i tried it with my data frame and column names in that command, but i get an Error: Error in gsub(paste0(".*?($|'|", paste(paste0("\\", char.keep), collapse = "|"),  : 
  assertion 'tree->num_tags == num_tags' failed in executing regexp: file 'tre-compile.c', line 627 - i have no idea what this means!

Comment: Me neither.  You haven't provided data and I don't know which qdap function you're using that produced that error.